# Is it possible to mutate a property/variable directly upon initialization?

Tags: swift

I was thinking something in the lines of the code-snippet below which obviously does not work but conveys my intention. This one gives the error message *variable used within its own initial value*.

```
private let formatter = NumberFormatter() {
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 6
}
```

Comment: I am completely new to Swift, and kind of new to asking questions on Stack Overflow. Please excuse me if I use the wrong names or terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot mutate a property within its own initialization. 
What you can do is to make the initial value of the property an
"immediately evaluated closure":

```
private let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let fmt = NumberFormatter()
    fmt.maximumFractionDigits = 6
    // ...
    return fmt
}()
```

This creates an `NumberFormatter`, sets the desired properties,
and assigns the result to the `formatter` property.

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome! Exactly does what I want it to do!

Answer (score 0):

I think that's initializer's job, doing something like this is standard:

```
class NumberFormatter {
    var maximumFractionDigits: Int = 0

    init(maximumFractionDigits: Int) {
        self.maximumFractionDigits = maximumFractionDigits
    }
}

let formatter = NumberFormatter(maximumFractionDigits: 6)
```